# Twitter search problem

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

Is it possible, using date ranges, to find this tweet? -

https://twitter.com/htGOIW/status/855615155123625984 (5:52 AM · 22 апр. 2017 г.)

I try searching with the following command, but to no avail -

([link](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3AhtGOIW%20include%3Anativeretweets%20since%3A2017-04-22_05%3A50%3A00_JST%20until%3A2017-04-22_05%3A52%3A00_JST&src=typed_query&f=live)) — `[from:htGOIW include:nativeretweets since:2017-04-22_05:50:00_JST until:2017-04-22_05:52:00_JST][2]`

Sorry my english!